# Django/Python: views.py and passing strings of text

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-views

So in my `template`, I have the following code:

```
<span class="state-txt">{{ state }}</span>
```

In my `views.py`, it's handled with the following if/else loop:

```
if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)            
                state = "You're successfully logged in!"
                return render_to_response('uc/portal/index.html', {'state':state, 'username':username}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
            else:
                state = "Your account is not active, please contact UC admin."
        else:
            state = "Your username and/or password were incorrect."
```

Essentially, it's working fine at the moment but I want each `state` to be able to contain different <`img`> tags, but when I just type `state = "<img src="some.jpg"> Your username and/or password were incorrect."` The html doesn't render correctly. Is there some way to do what I'm trying to do in Django, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: I think you should look into [the messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/messages/) instead of using 'state'. That way, you might be able to write styles for ERROR, INFO, etc instead of adding images to your variables.

Comment: That's actually a really good idea - I love the simplicity of @karthikr's answer below - any reason to suspect his implementation isn't good enough?

Comment: Thanks. No, his answer's just as good. it's just another approach. `:)`

Comment: I'm going to be looking into the messages framework, so definitely appreciate your input as well! Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just pass the image URL in the context from the view, and consume that in the template. Something like this:

```
if user:
    if user.is_active:
        login(request, user)            
        state = "You're successfully logged in!"
        state_img = success_image_url
        return render_to_response('uc/portal/index.html', 
                 {'state': state, 
                  'state_img': state_img, 
                  'username':username
                 }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        state_img = inactive_image_url
        state = "Your account is not active, please contact UC admin."
else:
    state_img = invalid_credentials_url
    state = "Your username and/or password were incorrect."
```

and in the template

```
<span class="state-txt">
    <img src="{{state_img}}" />{{ state }}
</span>
```

Comment: Oh wow yeah this seems really obvious - especially coming out of php I should have thought of this immediately!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For completeness' sake, as karthikr already posted an excellent solution:

The reason the html doesn't render correctly, is because the Django template language automatically assumes that all output by `{{ ... }}` is not safe, all symbols that have a special meaning in HTML will be escaped (`<` becomes `&lt;` etc.).

To render a string as pure HTML code, use the `safe` filter.

views.py:

```
state = "<img src="some.jpg" /> Your username and/or password were incorrect."
```

index.html:

```
<span class="state-txt">{{ state|safe }}</span>
```

Comment: Gorgeous, thank you so much for explaining this. I'm really looking forward to getting the hang of Django !

Answer (score 0):

Don't render the image. try if else

view.py

```
if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)            
            state = True
            return render_to_response('uc/portal/index.html', {'state':state, 'username':username}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            state = False
    else:
        state = False
```

in template

```
{%if state %}  
   <img></img>
   you are successfully logged in.
{%endif%}
```

Comment: I am using the state to give specific login error messages, so your solution isn't quite what I am looking for. However thanks for the tip!